# Unable to get expected design for header

Tags: html, css, vtigercrm

In short, my question is, how to get this output:

[image]

Let me tell what I have tried so far, I had copied html like in this way:

[image]

Html I got:

```
<div class="global-nav clearfix">
        <div class="company-logo-container">
     <a href="#" class="company-logo">
         <img src="logo.png" alt="logo.png">
     </a>
 </div>
 <div id="appnavigator" class="app-navigator-container app-switcher-container" data-app-class="vicon-dashboard">
     <div class="app-navigator textOverflowEllipsis p-l-0" title="Menu">
         <i class="vicon-menu cursorPointer f-24 verticalAlignMiddle vtMenuIcon"></i>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="search-links-container hidden-sm vt-search-container">
     <div class="search-link hidden-xs">
         <div class="searchInput input-group">
                 <input class="keyword-input form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type here and press ENTER to start your search" value="">
                 <span class="search-Icon cursorPointer input-group-addon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                 <span class="input-group-addon addon-divider"></span>
                 <span id="adv-search" class="adv-search cursorPointer input-group-addon" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
         </div>
                 <div class="recentlyAccesedItemList">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>  
 <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right global-actions">
     <div class="billing-status-container hidden-sm hidden-md pull-left">
         <div class="notificationMessageHolder hidden-xs" style="padding-top: 11px;"><a class="d-btn f-13 alignMiddle display-inline-block f-w" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="15 days left in free trial. Click to subscribe" href="index.php?module=Ondemand&amp;view=Billing" style="padding: 4px 8px !important;background: #ff5252 !important;">15 days left</a></div>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" id="picklistSortTourStatus" value="completed">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav topbar-icons"><li id="implementation-score" style="padding-top: 11px;">                                  <a class="p-o-btn f-13" style="padding: 2px 8px !important;" title="Your CRM implementation score">                                     <i class="fa vicon-rocket noHoverCss verticalAlignMiddleImp" style="font-size: 20px !important;"></i>&nbsp;                                     <span class="verticalAlignMiddleImp score">7%</span>                                    </a>                                </li>

         <li id="topbar-quickcreate">
             <div class="dropdown">
                 <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                     <a href="#" id="menubar_quickCreate" class="qc-button fa fa-plus-circle" title="Quick Create" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                 </span>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu quickCreateContainer" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="width:550px;max-height: 85vh; overflow-y: auto;">
                     <li class="title p-xy-16 f-16">
                         Quick Create
                     </li>
                     <hr>
                     <li id="quickCreateModules" class="container-fluid">
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 p-xy-16 p-y-8" oncontextmenu="return false;">
                                 <div class="row">
                                                                                                                                                                     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Campaigns" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="Campaigns" title="Campaign" data-url="index.php?module=Campaigns&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                                                                                         <i class="vicon-campaigns pull-left"></i>
                                                                                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">Campaign</span>
                                                 </a>
                                             </div>

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Contacts" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="Contacts" title="Contact" data-url="index.php?module=Contacts&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                                                                                         <i class="vicon-contacts pull-left"></i>
                                                                                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">Contact</span>
                                                 </a>
                                             </div>

                                                                                                 <div class="quickCreateSpecificDropDown  quickcreateRow dropdown">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Documents" class="quickCreateModuleSubmenu dropdown-toggle nowrap" data-name="Documents" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Document" data-url="index.php?module=Documents&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                     <i class="vicon-documents pull-left"></i>
                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">
                                                         Document
                                                         <i class="fa fa-caret-down quickcreateMoreDropdownAction"></i>
                                                     </span>
                                                 </a>

                                                 <ul class="dropdown-menu quickcreateMoreDropdown dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="menubar_quickCreate_Documents">
                                                     <li class="dropdown-header"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> File Upload</li>
                                                     <li id="VtigerAction">
                                                         <a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.uploadTo('Vtiger')">
                                                             <img style="  margin-top: -3px;margin-right: 4%;" title="Vtiger" alt="Vtiger" src="">
                                                             To Vtiger
                                                         </a>
                                                     </li>
                                                                                                                     <li id="GoogleDriveUploadAction">
                                                         <a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.authorize('GoogleDrive',undefined,undefined,'upload')">
                                                             <img style="  margin-top: -3px;margin-right: 4%;" title="Vtiger" alt="Vtiger" src="Google_Drive.png">
                                                             To GoogleDrive
                                                         </a>
                                                     </li>
                                                     <li id="DropboxUploadAction">
                                                         <a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.authorize('Dropbox',undefined,undefined,'upload')">
                                                             <img style="  margin-top: -3px;margin-right: 4%;" title="Vtiger" alt="Vtiger" src="Dropbox.png">
                                                             To Dropbox
                                                         </a>
                                                     </li>
                                                     <li role="separator" class="divider m-xy-0"></li>
                                                     <li class="dropdown-header"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> Link External Document</li>
                                                     <li id="GoogleDriveSelectAction">
                                                         <a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.authorize('GoogleDrive',undefined,undefined,'select')">
                                                             <img style="  margin-top: -3px;margin-right: 4%;" title="Vtiger" alt="Vtiger" src="Google_Drive.png">
                                                             From GoogleDrive
                                                         </a>
                                                     </li>
                                                     <li id="DropboxSelectAction">
                                                         <a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.authorize('Dropbox',undefined,undefined,'select')">
                                                             <img style="  margin-top: -3px;margin-right: 4%;" title="Vtiger" alt="Vtiger" src="Dropbox.png">
                                                             From Dropbox
                                                         </a>
                                                     </li>
                                                     <li id="shareDocument"><a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.createDocument('E')">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; From File Url</a></li>
                                                     <li role="separator" class="divider m-xy-0"></li>
                                                     <li id="createDocument"><a href="javascript:Documents_Index_Js.createDocument('W')"><i class="fa-plus"></i> Create New Document</a></li>
                                                 </ul>
                                             </div>

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Employees" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="Employees" title="Employee" data-url="index.php?module=Employees&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                                                                                         <i class="vicon-employees pull-left"></i>
                                                                                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">Employee</span>
                                                 </a>
                                             </div>
                                                                                                                                                 </div>
                                         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Events" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="Events" title="Event" data-url="index.php?module=Events&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="vicon-calendar pull-left"></i><span class="quick-create-module">Event</span></a>
                                             </div>

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Potentials" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="Potentials" title="Opportunity" data-url="index.php?module=Potentials&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                                                                                         <i class="vicon-potentials pull-left"></i>
                                                                                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">Opportunity</span>
                                                 </a>
                                             </div>

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_Accounts" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="Accounts" title="Organization" data-url="index.php?module=Accounts&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                                                                                         <i class="vicon-accounts pull-left"></i>
                                                                                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">Organization</span>
                                                 </a>
                                             </div>

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
                                                 <a id="menubar_quickCreate_PriceBooks" class="quickCreateModule nowrap" data-name="PriceBooks" title="Price Book" data-url="index.php?module=PriceBooks&amp;view=QuickCreateAjax" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                                                                                                         <i class="vicon-pricebooks pull-left"></i>
                                                                                                                     <span class="quick-create-module">Price Book</span>
                                                 </a>
                                             </div>
                                                                                                                                                 </div>
                                         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

                                                                                                 <div class=" quickcreateRow">
```

[Remove some lines because facing validation error, max length exceed]

css I got from actual v-tiger source:

[image]

Now while running I am getting this:

[image]

Please guide me to get desired output.. or please tell me, is there any other way to get snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I would code the header like this:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="exaple example example example.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="example, example, example">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>example</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="example.png" />
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="contenedor">
                <a href="index.html"><div class="logo">example</div></a>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">x</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">x</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>`
```

Keep in mind that the Css has to be like this:

```
  h* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: oswald, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    background:url(bg2.jpg), #000;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}

.contenedor {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
}

#particles-js {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

header {
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
}

header .menu {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    float:left;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:80px;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
}

header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:0 20px;
    line-height:80px;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.social {
    position: fixed; /* Hacemos que la posiciÃģn en pantalla sea fija para que siempre se muestre en pantalla*/
    left: 0; /* Establecemos la barra en la izquierda */
    top: 200px; /* Bajamos la barra 200px de arriba a abajo */
    z-index: 2000; /* Utilizamos la propiedad z-index para que no se superponga algÃšn otro elemento como sliders, galerÃ­as, etc */
}

    .social ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .social ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color:#fff;
        background: #000;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
        -o-transition:all 500ms ease;
        transition:all 500ms ease; /* Establecemos una transiciÃģn a todas las propiedades */
    }

    .social ul li .icon-facebook {background:#3b5998;} /* Establecemos los colores de cada red social, aprovechando su class */
    .social ul li .icon-twitter {background: #00abf0;}
    .social ul li .icon-instagram {background: #ff1a75;}
    .social ul li .icon-mail {background: #808080;}
    .social ul li .icon-youtube {background: #ff0000;}
    .social ul li .icon-linkedin {background: #3F66F5;}

    .social ul li a:hover {
        background: #000; /* Cambiamos el fondo cuando el usuario pase el mouse */
        padding: 10px 30px; /* Hacemos mas grande el espacio cuando el usuario pase el mouse */
    }


.texto {
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    padding:200px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.texto h2, .texto p {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.texto h2 {
    font-size:40px;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.texto p {
    font-size:20px;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

.principal {
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
}

.principal article {
    padding:20px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.principal article p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height:24px;
    font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.principal article .fecha {
    color:#939393;
    /*footer*/
}
```

And you may add the fonts like this:

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?up8oq2');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?up8oq2#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?up8oq2') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?up8oq2') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?up8oq2#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-home:before {
  content: "\e900";
}
.icon-home2:before {
  content: "\e901";
}
.icon-home3:before {
  content: "\e902";
}
.icon-office:before {
  content: "\e903";
}
.icon-newspaper:before {
  content: "\e904";
}
.icon-pencil:before {
  content: "\e905";
}
.icon-pencil2:before {
  content: "\e906";
}
.icon-quill:before {
  content: "\e907";
}
.icon-pen:before {
  content: "\e908";
}
.icon-blog:before {
  content: "\e909";
}
.icon-eyedropper:before {
  content: "\e90a";
}
.icon-droplet:before {
  content: "\e90b";
}
.icon-paint-format:before {
  content: "\e90c";
}
.icon-image:before {
  content: "\e90d";
}
.icon-images:before {
  content: "\e90e";
}
.icon-camera:before {
  content: "\e90f";
}
.icon-headphones:before {
  content: "\e910";
}
.icon-music:before {
  content: "\e911";
}
.icon-play:before {
  content: "\e912";
}
.icon-film:before {
  content: "\e913";
}
.icon-video-camera:before {
  content: "\e914";
}
.icon-dice:before {
  content: "\e915";
}
.icon-pacman:before {
  content: "\e916";
}
.icon-spades:before {
  content: "\e917";
}
.icon-clubs:before {
  content: "\e918";
}
.icon-diamonds:before {
  content: "\e919";
}
.icon-bullhorn:before {
  content: "\e91a";
}
.icon-connection:before {
  content: "\e91b";
}
.icon-podcast:before {
  content: "\e91c";
}
.icon-feed:before {
  content: "\e91d";
}
.icon-mic:before {
  content: "\e91e";
}
.icon-book:before {
  content: "\e91f";
}
.icon-books:before {
  content: "\e920";
}
.icon-library:before {
  content: "\e921";
}
.icon-file-text:before {
  content: "\e922";
}
.icon-profile:before {
  content: "\e923";
}
.icon-file-empty:before {
  content: "\e924";
}
.icon-files-empty:before {
  content: "\e925";
}
.icon-file-text2:before {
  content: "\e926";
}
.icon-file-picture:before {
  content: "\e927";
}
.icon-file-music:before {
  content: "\e928";
}
.icon-file-play:before {
  content: "\e929";
}
.icon-file-video:before {
  content: "\e92a";
}
.icon-file-zip:before {
  content: "\e92b";
}
.icon-copy:before {
  content: "\e92c";
}
.icon-paste:before {
  content: "\e92d";
}
.icon-stack:before {
  content: "\e92e";
}
.icon-folder:before {
  content: "\e92f";
}
.icon-folder-open:before {
  content: "\e930";
}
.icon-folder-plus:before {
  content: "\e931";
}
.icon-folder-minus:before {
  content: "\e932";
}
.icon-folder-download:before {
  content: "\e933";
}
.icon-folder-upload:before {
  content: "\e934";
}
.icon-price-tag:before {
  content: "\e935";
}
.icon-price-tags:before {
  content: "\e936";
}
.icon-barcode:before {
  content: "\e937";
}
.icon-qrcode:before {
  content: "\e938";
}
.icon-ticket:before {
  content: "\e939";
}
.icon-cart:before {
  content: "\e93a";
}
.icon-coin-dollar:before {
  content: "\e93b";
}
.icon-coin-euro:before {
  content: "\e93c";
}
.icon-coin-pound:before {
  content: "\e93d";
}
.icon-coin-yen:before {
  content: "\e93e";
}
.icon-credit-card:before {
  content: "\e93f";
}
.icon-calculator:before {
  content: "\e940";
}
.icon-lifebuoy:before {
  content: "\e941";
}
.icon-phone:before {
  content: "\e942";
}
.icon-phone-hang-up:before {
  content: "\e943";
}
.icon-address-book:before {
  content: "\e944";
}
.icon-envelop:before {
  content: "\e945";
}
.icon-pushpin:before {
  content: "\e946";
}
.icon-location:before {
  content: "\e947";
}
.icon-location2:before {
  content: "\e948";
}
.icon-compass:before {
  content: "\e949";
}
.icon-compass2:before {
  content: "\e94a";
}
.icon-map:before {
  content: "\e94b";
}
.icon-map2:before {
  content: "\e94c";
}
.icon-history:before {
  content: "\e94d";
}
.icon-clock:before {
  content: "\e94e";
}
.icon-clock2:before {
  content: "\e94f";
}
.icon-alarm:before {
  content: "\e950";
}
.icon-bell:before {
  content: "\e951";
}
.icon-stopwatch:before {
  content: "\e952";
}
.icon-calendar:before {
  content: "\e953";
}
.icon-printer:before {
  content: "\e954";
}
.icon-keyboard:before {
  content: "\e955";
}
.icon-display:before {
  content: "\e956";
}
.icon-laptop:before {
  content: "\e957";
}
.icon-mobile:before {
  content: "\e958";
}
.icon-mobile2:before {
  content: "\e959";
}
.icon-tablet:before {
  content: "\e95a";
}
.icon-tv:before {
  content: "\e95b";
}
.icon-drawer:before {
  content: "\e95c";
}
.icon-drawer2:before {
  content: "\e95d";
}
.icon-box-add:before {
  content: "\e95e";
}
.icon-box-remove:before {
  content: "\e95f";
}
.icon-download:before {
  content: "\e960";
}
.icon-upload:before {
  content: "\e961";
}
.icon-floppy-disk:before {
  content: "\e962";
}
.icon-drive:before {
  content: "\e963";
}
.icon-database:before {
  content: "\e964";
}
.icon-undo:before {
  content: "\e965";
}
.icon-redo:before {
  content: "\e966";
}
.icon-undo2:before {
  content: "\e967";
}
.icon-redo2:before {
  content: "\e968";
}
.icon-forward:before {
  content: "\e969";
}
.icon-reply:before {
  content: "\e96a";
}
.icon-bubble:before {
  content: "\e96b";
}
.icon-bubbles:before {
  content: "\e96c";
}
.icon-quotes-right:before {
  content: "\e978";
}
.icon-hour-glass:before {
  content: "\e979";
}
.icon-spinner:before {
  content: "\e97a";
}
.icon-spinner2:before {
  content: "\e97b";
}
.icon-zoom-in:before {
  content: "\e987";
}
.icon-zoom-out:before {
  content: "\e988";
}
.icon-enlarge:before {
  content: "\e989";
}
.icon-shrink:before {
  content: "\e98a";
}
.icon-hammer:before {
  content: "\e996";
}
.icon-magic-wand:before {
  content: "\e997";
}
.icon-aid-kit:before {
  content: "\e998";
}
.icon-bug:before {
  content: "\e999";
}
.icon-rocket:before {
  content: "\e9a5";
}
.icon-meter:before {
  content: "\e9a6";
}
.icon-meter2:before {
  content: "\e9a7";
}
.icon-hammer2:before {
  content: "\e9a8";
}
.icon-shield:before {
  content: "\e9b4";
}
.icon-power:before {
  content: "\e9b5";
}
.icon-switch:before {
  content: "\e9b6";
}
.icon-power-cord:before {
  content: "\e9b7";
}
.icon-cloud-upload:before {
  content: "\e9c3";
}
.icon-cloud-check:before {
  content: "\e9c4";
}
.icon-download2:before {
  content: "\e9c5";
}
.icon-upload2:before {
  content: "\e9c6";
}
.icon-bookmark:before {
  content: "\e9d2";
}
.icon-bookmarks:before {
  content: "\e9d3";
}
.icon-sun:before {
  content: "\e9d4";
}
.icon-contrast:before {
  content: "\e9d5";
}
.icon-smile:before {
  content: "\e9e1";
}
.icon-smile2:before {
  content: "\e9e2";
}
.icon-tongue:before {
  content: "\e9e3";
}
.icon-tongue2:before {
  content: "\e9e4";
}
.icon-evil2:before {
  content: "\e9f0";
}
.icon-shocked:before {
  content: "\e9f1";
}
.icon-shocked2:before {
  content: "\e9f2";
}
.icon-baffled:before {
  content: "\e9f3";
}
.icon-frustrated:before {
  content: "\e9ff";
}
.icon-frustrated2:before {
  content: "\ea00";
}
.icon-crying:before {
  content: "\ea01";
}
.icon-crying2:before {
  content: "\ea02";
}
.icon-blocked:before {
  content: "\ea0e";
}
.icon-cross:before {
  content: "\ea0f";
}
.icon-checkmark:before {
  content: "\ea10";
}
.icon-checkmark2:before {
  content: "\ea11";
}
.icon-pause2:before {
  content: "\ea1d";
}
.icon-stop2:before {
  content: "\ea1e";
}
.icon-backward2:before {
  content: "\ea1f";
}
.icon-forward3:before {
  content: "\ea20";
}
.icon-volume-decrease:before {
  content: "\ea2c";
}
.icon-loop:before {
  content: "\ea2d";
}
.icon-loop2:before {
  content: "\ea2e";
}
.icon-infinite:before {
  content: "\ea2f";
}
.icon-arrow-down-left2:before {
  content: "\ea3f";
}
.icon-arrow-left2:before {
  content: "\ea40";
}
.icon-circle-up:before {
  content: "\ea41";
}
.icon-circle-right:before {
  content: "\ea42";
}
.icon-circle-down:before {
  content: "\ea43";
}
.icon-circle-left:before {
  content: "\ea44";
}
.icon-tab:before {
  content: "\ea45";
}
.icon-move-up:before {
  content: "\ea46";
}
.icon-move-down:before {
  content: "\ea47";
}
.icon-sort-alpha-asc:before {
  content: "\ea48";
}
.icon-sort-alpha-desc:before {
  content: "\ea49";
}
.icon-command:before {
  content: "\ea4e";
}
.icon-shift:before {
  content: "\ea4f";
}
.icon-ctrl:before {
  content: "\ea50";
}
.icon-opt:before {
  content: "\ea51";
}
.icon-checkbox-checked:before {
  content: "\ea52";
}
.icon-checkbox-unchecked:before {
  content: "\ea53";
}
.icon-radio-checked:before {
  content: "\ea54";
}
.icon-radio-checked2:before {
  content: "\ea55";
}
.icon-radio-unchecked:before {
  content: "\ea56";
}
.icon-crop:before {
  content: "\ea57";
}
.icon-make-group:before {
  content: "\ea58";
}
.icon-ligature:before {
  content: "\ea5d";
}
.icon-ligature2:before {
  content: "\ea5e";
}
.icon-text-height:before {
  content: "\ea5f";
}
.icon-text-width:before {
  content: "\ea60";
}
.icon-font-size:before {
  content: "\ea61";
}
.icon-bold:before {
  content: "\ea62";
}
.icon-underline:before {
  content: "\ea63";
}
.icon-italic:before {
  content: "\ea64";
}
.icon-strikethrough:before {
  content: "\ea65";
}
.icon-omega:before {
  content: "\ea66";
}
.icon-sigma:before {
  content: "\ea67";
}
.icon-subscript2:before {
  content: "\ea6c";
}
.icon-text-color:before {
  content: "\ea6d";
}
.icon-pagebreak:before {
  content: "\ea6e";
}
.icon-clear-formatting:before {
  content: "\ea6f";
}
.icon-table:before {
  content: "\ea70";
}
.icon-table2:before {
  content: "\ea71";
}
.icon-insert-template:before {
  content: "\ea72";
}
.icon-pilcrow:before {
  content: "\ea73";
}
.icon-ltr:before {
  content: "\ea74";
}
.icon-rtl:before {
  content: "\ea75";
}
.icon-section:before {
  content: "\ea76";
}
.icon-indent-increase:before {
  content: "\ea7b";
}
.icon-indent-decrease:before {
  content: "\ea7c";
}
.icon-share:before {
  content: "\ea7d";
}
.icon-new-tab:before {
  content: "\ea7e";
}
.icon-embed:before {
  content: "\ea7f";
}
.icon-embed2:before {
  content: "\ea80";
}
.icon-terminal:before {
  content: "\ea81";
}
.icon-share2:before {
  content: "\ea82";
}
.icon-mail:before {
  content: "\ea83";
}
.icon-mail2:before {
  content: "\ea84";
}
.icon-mail3:before {
  content: "\ea85";
}
.icon-mail4:before {
  content: "\ea86";
}
.icon-amazon:before {
  content: "\ea87";
}
.icon-google:before {
  content: "\ea88";
}
.icon-google2:before {
  content: "\ea89";
}
.icon-google3:before {
  content: "\ea8a";
}
.icon-google-plus:before {
  content: "\ea8b";
}
.icon-google-plus2:before {
  content: "\ea8c";
}
.icon-google-plus3:before {
  content: "\ea8d";
}
.icon-hangouts:before {
  content: "\ea8e";
}
.icon-google-drive:before {
  content: "\ea8f";
}
.icon-facebook:before {
  content: "\ea90";
}
.icon-facebook2:before {
  content: "\ea91";
}
.icon-instagram:before {
  content: "\ea92";
}
.icon-whatsapp:before {
  content: "\ea93";
}
.icon-spotify:before {
  content: "\ea94";
}
.icon-telegram:before {
  content: "\ea95";
}
.icon-twitter:before {
  content: "\ea96";
}
.icon-vine:before {
  content: "\ea97";
}
.icon-vk:before {
  content: "\ea98";
}
.icon-renren:before {
  content: "\ea99";
}
.icon-sina-weibo:before {
  content: "\ea9a";
}
.icon-rss:before {
  content: "\ea9b";
}
.icon-rss2:before {
  content: "\ea9c";
}
.icon-youtube:before {
  content: "\ea9d";
}
.icon-youtube2:before {
  content: "\ea9e";
}
.icon-twitch:before {
  content: "\ea9f";
}
.icon-vimeo:before {
  content: "\eaa0";
}
.icon-vimeo2:before {
  content: "\eaa1";
}
.icon-lanyrd:before {
  content: "\eaa2";
}
.icon-flickr:before {
  content: "\eaa3";
}
.icon-dribbble:before {
  content: "\eaa7";
}
.icon-behance:before {
  content: "\eaa8";
}
.icon-behance2:before {
  content: "\eaa9";
}
.icon-deviantart:before {
  content: "\eaaa";
}
.icon-500px:before {
  content: "\eaab";
}
.icon-steam:before {
  content: "\eaac";
}
.icon-steam2:before {
  content: "\eaad";
}
.icon-dropbox:before {
  content: "\eaae";
}
.icon-onedrive:before {
  content: "\eaaf";
}
.icon-github:before {
  content: "\eab0";
}
.icon-npm:before {
  content: "\eab1";
}
.icon-basecamp:before {
  content: "\eab2";
}
.icon-trello:before {
  content: "\eab3";
}
.icon-wordpress:before {
  content: "\eab4";
}
.icon-joomla:before {
  content: "\eab5";
}
.icon-ello:before {
  content: "\eab6";
}
.icon-blogger:before {
  content: "\eab7";
}
.icon-blogger2:before {
  content: "\eab8";
}
.icon-tumblr:before {
  content: "\eab9";
}
.icon-tumblr2:before {
  content: "\eaba";
}
.icon-yahoo:before {
  content: "\eabb";
}
.icon-yahoo2:before {
  content: "\eabc";
}
.icon-tux:before {
  content: "\eabd";
}
.icon-appleinc:before {
  content: "\eabe";
}
.icon-finder:before {
  content: "\eabf";
}
.icon-android:before {
  content: "\eac0";
}
.icon-windows:before {
  content: "\eac1";
}
.icon-soundcloud2:before {
  content: "\eac4";
}
.icon-skype:before {
  content: "\eac5";
}
.icon-reddit:before {
  content: "\eac6";
}
.icon-hackernews:before {
  content: "\eac7";
}
.icon-wikipedia:before {
  content: "\eac8";
}
.icon-linkedin:before {
  content: "\eac9";
}
.icon-linkedin2:before {
  content: "\eaca";
}
.icon-lastfm:before {
  content: "\eacb";
}
.icon-delicious:before {
  content: "\eacd";
}
.icon-stackoverflow:before {
  content: "\ead0";
}
.icon-xing:before {
  content: "\ead3";
}
.icon-xing2:before {
  content: "\ead4";
}
.icon-flattr:before {
  content: "\ead5";
}
.icon-foursquare:before {
  content: "\ead6";
}
.icon-yelp:before {
  content: "\ead7";
}
.icon-paypal:before {
  content: "\ead8";
}
.icon-chrome:before {
  content: "\ead9";
}
.icon-IE:before {
  content: "\eadb";
}
.icon-edge:before {
  content: "\eadc";
}
.icon-IcoMoon:before {
  content: "\eaea";
}
```